# Inequality of distances in a graph

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, optimization, linear-programming

Certainly it's obvious but I can't catch the reason behind it.

Why do we have :

> Let $D= (V,A)$ be a directed graph, $w:A \to \mathbb R$ be arc weights
>    and $s \in V$. Denote with $d(s,v)$ the length of the shortest path
>    from $s$ to $v$ in $D$, subject to $w$.
>
> If there are no negative cycles in $D$, then we have $$ \forall (u,v)
>  \in A : d(s,v) \leq d(s,u)  + w(u,v) $$ 
>   (or equivalently $$ \forall (u,v)
>  \in A : d(s,v)- d(s,u) \leq
>  w(u,v)). $$

I don't understand what's the inner thoughts of this sentence : 
$$d(s,v) \leq d(s,u)  + w(u,v) $$ 
I don't know if it comes from the definition of distance on the graph (which I only know how to compute using the Bellman Ford algorithm), from a triangular inequality or from anything else. How do you know that one side is less than the other ? When do we have equality, strict inequality ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$d(s,v)$ is the weighted length of the shortest path from $s$ to $v$.

$\exists (u,v):d(s,v) > d(s,u) + w(u,v)$ is a contradiction, because going from $s$ to $u$ and then by that $(u,v)$ arc is a shorter path than whatever path $d(s,v)$ takes.

Comment: Thx for the answer, can you also consider the other points i mentionned? When do you have strict and equality?

Comment: @MarineGalantin One example when equality ($\forall (u,v)\in A: d(s,v) = d(s,u) + w(u,v)$) holds is if the directed graph is a tree outward from $s$. Or more generally when the graph is acyclic and only outward from $s$ where all paths from $s$ to each $u\in V$ has the same weighted length. Or more generally and additionally some $u,v\in V$ with $d(s,u) = d(s,v)$ has arcs of zero weight between them, making the graph possibly cyclic. I am sure there are more examples beyond my imagination, so I am not putting a definitive answer above.

Comment: thanks for the answer. Why are you emphazing on the fact that the graph is acyclic ? what would happen if it wasn't ? If you also have an example for the strict case that would be awesome and solve my problem around that question.

Comment: Yeah i found a counter example. Let s build a cycle u, v, s. S to u for 1, u to v for 2 and s to v 0. Then $d(s, v) =0$.